# "method not found" error when using a project that have references added using the HtmlSanitizer nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a C# class library project called *Helpers* which uses the nuget called *HtmlSanitizer*.

In my web application (which is located inside the same solution), I'm referencing the *Helpers* project. When I call one of the helper methods that instantiates a *HtmlSanitizer*, I get the following error:

> Method not found: 'Void Ganss.XSS.HtmlSanitizer..ctor(…)'

The error disappears if I add the *HtmlSanitizer* nuget to the web application.

Since my *Helpers* project is used in many other projects and web applications (and even referenced in other solutions), it is not viable for me to add the nuget to all of them (imagine the maintenance cost if I have to upgrade the version or use a different nuget…). What's the solution?

Comment: Is _HtmlSanitizer_ assembly correctly deployed to the target web app? (= is it inside its output folder) Is, by chance, the web app an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: It's a classic ASP.Net Web Forms project. You pointed me in the right direction. The DLL copied to the web app had the wrong version (even after a clean and rebuild). There was a previous version of the DLL that still existed somewhere on disk and that was being copied. I think there's a problem with this nuget as it adds references to HtmlSanitizer with version 3.0.0.0, which doesn't match the version of the DLL (all versions of the nuget add a reference to 3.0.0.0...) I'll report the problem to them. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because there are older version of the *HtmlSanitizer* DLL still present on disk. You need to clean the solution before building, and if not enough, manually delete the older DLLs from disk.

There might be a problem with the *HtmlSanitizer* nuget. It seems to add references to *HtmlSanitizer* version 3.0.0.0 to the project, which does not match the version of the DLL and which does not change either when you update the nuget. See bug [References to HtmlSanitizer have wrong version number when using the nuget](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/issues/142).